# Django How to generate value of attribute while initializing

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have a enum table **ServiceType** in my database which includes "Credit", "Investment" and "Insurance" and another table **Service** which have two columns - *type_id* and *type*. Is there a way to call method which will be generating value of *type* from value of *type_id* while initialization?

Should I use __init__ or maybe save?

*type* in **Service** is a ForeignKey to **ServiceType**

Thanks, sorry for my bad English.

So, I've tried something like this:

```
class Service(models.Model):  
  type_id = models.CharField(..)
  type    = models.ForeignKey('ServiceType', 
                              to_field = 'type',
                              default  = foo(type_id))

class ServiceType(models.Model):
  type = models.CharField(..)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer if anyone will be looking for it in future.

Things like that are managed by using *signals*. For above example I've used *pre_save* signal in function decorated as *reciver*.

In my understanding, *reciver* catches data before or after saving in database - way of doing it is based on type of *signal*. Those functions could basicly do anything, for example - change *type* of *Service* based on given *type_id*.